# Two BwuDatagrids on one page

Tags: dart, dartium, bwu-datagrid

I have polymer paper layout with paper-drawer-panel and two Polymer components contains BwuDatagrid elements. And I get some troubles when two components with bwu-datagrid tags rendered on one page:

[image]

But if didn't render component in paper-drawer-panel it's worked like so:

[image]

What it can be? And how I can fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue. There is a pull request https://github.com/bwu-dart/bwu_datagrid/pull/112 but I planned to implement this a bit differently.
I just didn't do it yet :-/

Thanks for using BWU Datagrid btw :)